# Log metrics with configuation in Pytorch Lightning using w&b

Tags: pytorch, metrics, pytorch-lightning, wandb

I am using PyTorch Lightning together with w&b and trying associate metrics with a finite set of configurations. In the [`LightningModule`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html) class I have defined the `test_step` as:

```py
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
  x, y_true, config_file =  batch
  y_pred = self.forward(x)
  accuracy = self.accuracy(y_pred, y_true)
  self.log("test/accuracy", accuracy)
```

Assuming (for simplicity) that the batch size is 1, this will log the accuracy for 1 sample and it will be displayed as a chart in the w&b dashboard.

I would like to associate this accuracy with some configuration of the experimental environment. This configuration might include BDP factor, bandwith delay, queue_size, location, etc. I don't want to plot the configurations I just want to be able to filter or group the accuracy by some configuration value.

The only solution I can come up with is to add these configurations as a querystring:

```py
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
  x, y_true, config_file =  batch
  # read values in config file
  # ...

  y_pred = self.forward(x)
  accuracy = self.accuracy(y_pred, y_true)
  self.log("test/BDP=2&delay=10ms&queue_size=10&topology=single/accuracy", accuracy)
```

Is there a better solution for this that integrates my desired functionality of being able to group and filter by values like BDP?

Answer (score 1):

I work at W&B. You could log your config variables using wandb.config, like so:

```
wandb.config['my_variable'] = 123
```

And then you'll be able to filter your charts by whatever config you'd logged. Or am I missing something.

Possibly the `save_hyperparameters` call might even grab these config values automatically (from the [WandbLogger docs here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/generated/pytorch_lightning.loggers.WandbLogger.html))

```
class LitModule(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwarg):
        self.save_hyperparameters()
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the recommended way of doing this. However, I have multiple variables that are only valid for the test set. So I am training the model once and testing it on multiple test sets configured in some specific way. Is it possible to update the configuration between consecutive "test runs", or do I need to rerun the whole process?

Comment: I posted a [similar question on the w&b community](https://community.wandb.ai/t/grouping-custom-metrics-by-configuration/1995/2) this week.